# Populate spinner from db only with Java?

Tags: java, android, mysql

Is it possible to populate a spinner with data from a MySQL database without using PHP? I've searched a lot on this matter and every example I can find includes a solution with PHP and most often JSON.

Comment: An spinner .... on which environment?

Comment: What do you mean? An Android spinner as the tag suggests.

Comment: Yes, but I mean: where's the data? You're invoking a webservice? Or you already have it on your App?

Comment: The data is simply in the db and most webservices to solve this uses php, right? So that is sort of part of my question. I want to connect to the DB and get the data from a certain table to the spinner. I'm not very confident in this area so feel free to correct me.

Comment: Ok, but the database where you want to get date from, is in your Android device? Or it is in a webserver?

Comment: As of now I'm just using a localhost db to get it working first.

Comment: Then you only need to access to database directly from Java. I'm going to post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to open a database connection from your Java App and get all the results you want.

For example:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = LlistaRevisionsClientsActivity.getDB(context);
Cursor cursorp = db.rawQuery("select * from table", null);
try
{
    if (cursorp.moveToFirst())
    {  
        if (productesRevisionsClientsCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
           do{
               lst.add(cursorp.getString(cursorp
                  .getColumnIndex("nom")));
           } while (cursorp.moveToNext());
        }  
   } 
 }finally
 {
   cursorp.close();
 }
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.productes_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lst);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_productes);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```